# main context gets in front of toolbar

Tags: android, layout, toolbar, appbar

I want to create a layout that has an appbar with a toolbar inside. Then I want a simple layout with my "window" main content. Looks pretty simples but, in the code, I get the layout with the button overlapping my toolbar, when I run it I get the appbar/toolbar covering the layout with the button, so that I cant see it.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you want your button to show inside toolbar?

Comment: No, I want it below my toolbar, outside of my appbar.

Comment: no one ? I believe its pretty easy, Its just me missing something :(

Comment: 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caXJN.png 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caXJN.png check both layouts, which one is good for you?

Comment: they look the same to me but I already solved the problem by adding         android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">. thanks

Comment: Oh sorry, I uploaded same image. This was second one https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFMnG.png